# Shell script to build CLI args for a PERL script

Tags: sh, double-quotes, single-quotes

I have a Jenkins job, triggered as a parameterized build. It accepts an optional String parameter (HOSTNAMES) that can be a comma separated list of hostnames.

I need to pass this comma separated list of hostnames as a command line argument to a PERL script (within Execute shell build step).

Here is how I process the input parameter and construct the command line argument within the execute shell build step:

```
cmd_options=''
echo hostnames is $HOSTNAMES
if [ "$HOSTNAMES" != "" ]
  then
  cmd_options+=" --hostnames \"$HOSTNAMES\""
fi
perl myscript.pl $cmd_options
```

In the console output of the build though, I see the argument being passed incorrectly. Here is the console output:

```
+ cmd_options=
+ echo hostnames is host1, host2
hostnames is host1, host2
+ '[' 'host1, host2' '!=' '' ']'
+ cmd_options+=' --hostnames "host1, host2"'
+ perl myscript.pl --hostnames '"host1,' 'host2"'
```

I want `myscript.pl` to be called this way:

```
perl myscript.pl --hostnames "host1, host2"
```

I have tried various ways of manipulating `$cmd_options` using single quotes and double quotes, but have been unsuccessful so far in getting it right. Any pointers at where I am going wrong?

Comment: Why don't you rewrite the Perl script instead?

Comment: I could do that. But I have posed this question more with the intent of trying to understand the finer details of shell scripting and what I am missing out on.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: Is `$HOSTNAMES` an environment variable or are you somehow obtaining its value from the command line arguments?

Comment: `$HOSTNAMES` would be an environment variable in the Jenkins build environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build a command, delay the interpolation and use `eval` to execute it.

```
HOSTNAMES='host1, host2'

cmd_options=''
if [ "$HOSTNAMES" != "" ]; then
   cmd_options+='--hostnames "$HOSTNAMES"'
fi

eval "prog $cmd_options"
```

---

A better solution is to use an array.

```
HOSTNAMES='host1, host2'

cmd_options=()
if [ "$HOSTNAMES" != "" ]; then
   cmd_options+=(--hostnames "$HOSTNAMES")
fi

prog "${cmd_options[@]}"
```

---

If `prog` is the following program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use feature qw( say );
say 0+@ARGV; say for @ARGV
```

Both snippets output the following:

```
2
--hostnames
host1, host2
```

Comment: I would very strongly recommend against using `eval` here, at least without being very sure the value of `HOSTNAMES` is safe.

Comment: @chepner, You are mistaken. The contents of `HOSTNAMES` is never passed to `eval`, so there's nothing to check.

Comment: Ah, missed that. The literal string `$HOSTNAMES` is passed to `eval`, which  does the parameter expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will not be able to embed a list inside `$cmd_options`,
as it prevents you from using the quotation-marks properly -
"escaping" the quotation-marks with the backslash (`\"`)
converts them to a regular `"` character - not a delimiter, and as such,
they are simply concatenated to the first and last items of the `$HOSTNAMES` list.

Suggest you *drop* this line:

```
cmd_options+=" --hostnames \"$HOSTNAMES\""
```

and, instead, use the following two lines, as needed
(this assumes you still need `$cmd_options` for passing other parameters)

```
perl myscript.pl $cmd_options --hostnames "$HOSTNAMES"
perl myscript.pl $cmd_options
```

Wrapped in an `if` statement, it should look like this:

```
if [ "$HOSTNAMES" != "" ]
then
  perl myscript.pl $cmd_options --hostnames "$HOSTNAMES"
else
  perl myscript.pl $cmd_options
fi
```

Another option is to make sure there are **no spaces** in the `$HOSTNAMES` list -
it will allow to pass the list as a single parameter and the quotation-marks will not be required anymore.

Comment: I think that they still need to include $cmd_options in case it has other options. So possibly something like `perl myscript.pl $cmd_options --hostnames "$HOSTNAMES" ` in the first case, and same thing but without the --hostnames option in the second case.

Comment: @Gonen can you explain a little about why `--hostnames \"$HOSTNAMES\"` doesn't simply result in `--hostnames "host1, host2"` when concatenated with `$cmd_options`?

Comment: @sockmonk, thanks - have updated my example with your comment.

Comment: @SindhuriKuppasad, the quotation-marks in your example are not a delimiter - they are simply the `"` character, concatenated to the first and last items of the `$HOSTNAMES` list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need the script's positional parameters any more, you can set them yourself. (This will work in any POSIX shell, where arrays are unavailable.)

```
# Save any positional parameters first, if necessary;
# we're going to overwrite them.
first_arg=$1
second_arg=$2
# etc.
set -- --hostnames "$HOSTNAMES"
perl myscript.pl "$@"
```